# Using JRebel for non webapp projects

Tags: java, maven, jrebel

I have a non-web app maven project which relies on Kafka which is my message queue. now in order to do computation on incoming messages I need to run 4 JAR files concurrently. How can I use JRebel in this case so I can change my code and I don’t have to recompile those JAR files every time and run it again?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Easiest is to setup JRebel using an IDE. JRebel has plugins for [IntelliJ](https://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/quickstart/intellij/), [Netbeans](https://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/quickstart/netbeans/) and [Eclipse](https://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/quickstart/eclipse/) all of which can also set up IDE run configurations automatically.

However, it's also possible to prepare your jar-s with [JRebel maven plugin](http://manuals.zeroturnaround.com/jrebel/standalone/maven.html).

If you want to run your JAR-files from command-line then IDE plugins contain instructions in JRebel settings > Startup > Run using CLI > Standalone application. Alternatively, you can find [more general CLI instructions here](http://manuals.zeroturnaround.com/jrebel/standalone/launch-quick-start.html).

Comment: I get this when I run it with JRebel java agent. `[IntelliJFSNotify] Event 'DIRTY' project_dir/target/classes/com/../` `[Core-Virtual] Evict cache for project_dir/target/classes` weird part is modified time on class file inside target/classes folder reflects the time when I modify the java file

Comment: Do you use Eclipse? It auto-compiles class file when saving java file.

Comment: Great. Now check the output when running jars. Do you see jrebel banner? Does it contain "will be monitored for changes" for you target/classes? Does it contain "Reloading class" for your changed class?

Comment: yes I get that... here are the logs
```JRebel: Starting logging to file: /Users/asav/.jrebel/jrebel.log
2015-11-25 10:48:07 JRebel: Directory '/Users/asav/Workspace/java/project/target/classes' will be monitored for changes.
2015-11-25 10:48:07 JRebel: Contacting myJRebel server ..
2015-11-25 10:48:09 JRebel:  ##########################################################
2015-11-25 10:48:09 JRebel:  JRebel Legacy Agent 6.2.7 
2015-11-25 10:48:09 JRebel:  (c) Copyright ZeroTurnaround AS, Estonia, Tartu.
2015-11-25 10:48:09 JRebel:  Over the last 1 days JRebel prevented```

Comment: The log doesn't fit into comment. Did JRebel reload your changes?